# Walk file tree recursively until level 2 with java only, turn command line program into GUI program

Tags: java, recursion, file-io

I am looking to adapt a script to have the following changes:

1) it shall not be started from the command line, but by not requiring command line inputs and shall be started simply by typing the parameters in fixed

2) if the program is started **recursively**, how do I define in the program that it shall only copy those files until the second level?
E.g. if I have:

```
File
File

Folder
-File
-File

-Subfolder
-File
-File
--Subsubfolder
--File
--File

-Subfolder
-File
-File
```

What it shall do is copy:
    File
    File

```
Folder
-File
-File

-Subfolder
-File
-File

-Subfolder
-File
-File
```

but not
    --Subsubfolder
    --File
    --File

The programming code:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;



public class Copy {

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if okay to overwrite a  file ("cp -i")
     */
    static boolean okayToOverwrite(Path file) {
        String answer = System.console().readLine("overwrite %s (yes/no)? ", file);
        return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    }

    /**
     * Copy source file to target location. If {@code prompt} is true then
     * prompt user to overwrite target if it exists. The {@code preserve}
     * parameter determines if file attributes should be copied/preserved.
     */
    static void copyFile(Path source, Path target, boolean prompt, boolean preserve) {
        CopyOption[] options = (preserve) ?
            new CopyOption[] { COPY_ATTRIBUTES, REPLACE_EXISTING } :
            new CopyOption[] { REPLACE_EXISTING };
        if (!prompt || Files.notExists(target) || okayToOverwrite(target)) {
            try {
                Files.copy(source, target, options);
            } catch (IOException x) {
                System.err.format("Unable to copy: %s: %s%n", source, x);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@code FileVisitor} that copies a file-tree ("cp -r")
     */
    static class TreeCopier implements FileVisitor<Path> {
        private final Path source;
        private final Path target;
        private final boolean prompt;
        private final boolean preserve;

        TreeCopier(Path source, Path target, boolean prompt, boolean preserve) {
            this.source = source;
            this.target = target;
            this.prompt = prompt;
            this.preserve = preserve;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            // before visiting entries in a directory we copy the directory
            // (okay if directory already exists).
            CopyOption[] options = (preserve) ?
                new CopyOption[] { COPY_ATTRIBUTES } : new CopyOption[0];

            Path newdir = target.resolve(source.relativize(dir));
            try {
                Files.copy(dir, newdir, options);
            } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException x) {
                // ignore
            } catch (IOException x) {
                System.err.format("Unable to create: %s: %s%n", newdir, x);
                return SKIP_SUBTREE;
            }
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            copyFile(file, target.resolve(source.relativize(file)),
                     prompt, preserve);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
            // fix up modification time of directory when done
            if (exc == null && preserve) {
                Path newdir = target.resolve(source.relativize(dir));
                try {
                    FileTime time = Files.getLastModifiedTime(dir);
                    Files.setLastModifiedTime(newdir, time);
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    System.err.format("Unable to copy all attributes to: %s: %s%n", newdir, x);
                }
            }
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
            if (exc instanceof FileSystemLoopException) {
                System.err.println("cycle detected: " + file);
            } else {
                System.err.format("Unable to copy: %s: %s%n", file, exc);
            }
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    static void usage() {
        System.err.println("java Copy [-ip] source... target");
        System.err.println("java Copy -r [-ip] source-dir... target");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean recursive = false;
        boolean prompt = false;
        boolean preserve = false;

        // process options
        int argi = 0;
        while (argi < args.length) {
            String arg = args[argi];
            if (!arg.startsWith("-"))
                break;
            if (arg.length() < 2)
                usage();
            for (int i=1; i<arg.length(); i++) {
                char c = arg.charAt(i);
                switch (c) {
                    case 'r' : recursive = true; break;
                    case 'i' : prompt = true; break;
                    case 'p' : preserve = true; break;
                    default : usage();
                }
            }
            argi++;
        }

        // remaining arguments are the source files(s) and the target location
        int remaining = args.length - argi;
        if (remaining < 2)
            usage();
        Path[] source = new Path[remaining-1];
        int i=0;
        while (remaining > 1) {
            source[i++] = Paths.get(args[argi++]);
            remaining--;
        }
        Path target = Paths.get(args[argi]);

        // check if target is a directory
        boolean isDir = Files.isDirectory(target);

        // copy each source file/directory to target
        for (i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
            Path dest = (isDir) ? target.resolve(source[i].getFileName()) : target;

            if (recursive) {
                // follow links when copying files
                EnumSet<FileVisitOption> opts = EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
                TreeCopier tc = new TreeCopier(source[i], dest, prompt, preserve);
                Files.walkFileTree(source[i], opts, 2, tc);
            } else {
                // not recursive so source must not be a directory
                if (Files.isDirectory(source[i])) {
                    System.err.format("%s: is a directory%n", source[i]);
                    continue;
                }
                copyFile(source[i], dest, prompt, preserve);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it sufficient to just write 2 instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE in the recursive function? How do I remove following the links?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK ... so you found some code at https:/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java/docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java ...

Comment: I guess that is the documentation that I adapted for my needs. There is no documentation for my specific question.

Comment: No.  It is not documentation.  It is an example that you copied.  There is documentation for how the APIs work.  Look in the javadocs.  Specifically at the javadoc for `Files`.  That should answer both of your questions.  Real programming is not about copy-and-pasting examples and asking someone to help you modify them.  The idea of the Oracle examples is that you read them in conjunction with the Oracle tutorials and the API documentation .... and learn what the examples are doing.  If you did that, you wouldn't need to ask questions like this one.